# Cómo uso el loop FOR en distintos data frame para hacer un reshape en R?

Tags: r, reshape

Tengo los siguientes data frame:

`b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7,...b100`

Y deseo hacer un reshape wide. Para ello cree mi función de la siguiente manera.

```
reshapeo<-function(x, id, valor, derecha){
  x<-subset(x, select=c(id,valor,derecha))
  x<-as.data.frame(x)
  x<-reshape(x, idvar = id, v.names = valor, timevar = derecha, direction = "wide")
```

Una vez definido mi función, quiero realizar el reshape para todos mis data frame, con la siguiente sintaxis.

```
x<-list(b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,..,b100)  # Una forma abreviada de escribir la lista
for (i in x) {
 i<-reshapeo(i, "ID", "VALOR", "TIME")
}
```

En lo cual me sale el siguiente mensaje de error:

```
"Warning message:
In reshapeWide(data, idvar = idvar, timevar = timevar, varying = varying,  :
  there are records with missing times, which will be dropped."
```

Si es un mensaje de error entiendo que se correría igual. Pero no logro obtener lo que deseo (mejor dicho, no corre). ¿Está mal especificado mi for? ¿Dónde estoy fallando?

Cómo podría solucionarlo. **Muchísimas gracias de antemano.**

Comment: Quizás el problema esté en el loop ¿iniciaste la estructura de datos `i` en la que se almacenará el output de de cada ciclo del bucle? De hecho no sé si es buena idea que se llame `i`, igual que el índice de control. Al parecer el `warning()` es un problema aparte y el problema está en el bucle.

Comment: Utilizando la siguiente sintaxis tampoco se puede `for (i in x) {
  assign(paste0("b_",i), reshapeo(i, "ID", "VALOR", "TIME"))
}
`

Comment: Gracias amigo, me salió con esta sintaxis:
x<-list(b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,..,b100)
y=c("b1","b2","b3",...,"b100")
for (i in 1:length(x)) {
  assign(paste0(y[i]), reshapeo(x[[i]], "I_POSTULACION_ID", "V_ADICIONAL", "V_RESPUESTA"))
}

Comment: @ARSENALCOYG puedes marcar la pregunta como solucionada indicando cuál fue la solución encontrada